# Find the newest file in a directory in python

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to find the newest file in a directory. However, max() is returning a "max() arg is empty sequence error" I've even tried passing in the exact path instead of the path variable.

```
def function(path):
   max(glob.iglob('path\*.map'), key=os.path.getctime)
   ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: But there are though...

Comment: Better yet, use `os.sep`, which will be backslash on Windows and forward slash on *nix.

Comment: `glob.iglob('path\*.map')` is finding nothing, how did you pass the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function, `path` is passed in as an argument, however, your glob spec is using the literal string `'path\*.map'`. So, unless you actually have a directory named `path` that contains `.map` files, `iglob()` will return an empty list, and `max()` will raise the exception that you see.

Instead you should substitute the value of the `path` variable into the glob spec string:

```
glob.iglob(r'{}\*.map'.format(path))
```

Now, assuming that the path and `.map` files do exist, you can find the most recent.

Also, you should use `os.path.join()` to construct the glob spec. Your function would then look like this:

```
def most_recent_map_file(path):
    glob_pattern = os.path.join(path, '*.map')
    return max(glob.iglob(glob_pattern), key=os.path.getctime)
```

`os.path.join()` is preferable because it will handle the different path separators of different OSes - `\` for Windows, `/` for *nix.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works perfectly:

Are you under windows?

Otherwise it's / and not \

```
max(glob.iglob('path/*.map'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

and make sure you are under the right path.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, double check your path, use full path as a first attempt.